VS Code - how to have dataframe show in interactive viewer rather than as a popup window when using view() function?
Currently coding in R in VS Code and trying to figure out how to have the output of the view() function appear in the editor rather than as a pop-up window.
When I use the view function on a dataframe, the dataframe will popup as a new window.
Ex. view(billing_summary), below is the following output.
enter image description here
How can I have it so that when I use view() the dataframe will show as a new tab in the editor/terminal? (Below).
enter image description here
Tried looking at enabling R Session Watcher, however it is already enabled.
https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/Interactive-viewers

Just did a full restart on my computer and the issue seems to have been solved, but if anyone knows the reason why this happened in the first place your advice would be greatly appreciated.
